# jQuery - Add and Remove class

Tags: jquery

The situation is that I have two buttons that each have a dedicated class. But when I click the about button I want the class to change to the highlightabout class, and then when I click the graph button I want the highlightabout class to revert to the about class and the graph class to change to the highlightgraph class. So they would switch accordingly when I click either button.

I have this script but I don't understand why it isn't working:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul><li><a class="about"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="graph"><span>Graphic Design</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

.CSS:

```
.about { background:url(../button/about_btn.png) no-repeat left center; width:160px; height:50px; float:left;cursor:pointer}
.graph { background:url(../button/graph_btn.png) no-repeat left center; width:160px; height:50px; float:left;cursor:pointer}
.highlightabout {background:url(../button/about_btn.png) no-repeat right center; width:160px; height:50px; float:left; cursor:pointer}
.highlightgraph {background:url(../button/graph_btn.png) no-repeat right center; width:160px; height:50px; float:left; cursor:pointer}
```

Script:

```
$('.about').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("about").addClass("highlightabout");
    $('.graph').removeClass("highlightgraph").addClass("graph");
});
$('.graph').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("graph").addClass("highlightgraph");
$('.about').removeClass("highlightabout").addClass("about");
});
```

Appreciate any help.

UPDATE: Extremely sorry for not adding the HTML, I didn't think it would help. Added the HTML/.CSS now also.

Comment: You should provide more information - errors, html, what exactly is not working...

Comment: Code given above doesn't tell anything about the error, please provide more information!

Comment: Works for me (or at least does what _I_ expect it to do): http://jsfiddle.net/zWJTG/

Comment: It's working, class is being added to the a tag. Just click 'About' here http://jsfiddle.net/4qYtJ/

Comment: Thank you for the responses but I added more updates to what I actually wanted to achieve, sorry that I didn't do this in the first but I actually thought it would have complicated matters.

Comment: Check out my answer and see the fiddle too.

Comment: Check the update, http://jsfiddle.net/4qYtJ/4/

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul><li><a id="about_button" class="about"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="graph_button" class="graph"><span>Graphic Design</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Instead of using the class I added an ID for the anchor tag. Thus the script looks like this:

```
$('#about_button').click(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("about").addClass("highlightabout");
   $('#graph_button').removeClass("highlightgraph").addClass("graph");
});

$('#graph_button').click(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("graph").addClass("highlightgraph");
   $('#about_button').removeClass("highlightabout").addClass("about");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DYfXC/)

Answer (score 0):

> $('.graph').removeClass("highlightgraph").addClass("graph");

Should that not be:

> $('.graph').removeClass("graph").addClass("highlightgraph");

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.about').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("about").addClass("highlightabout");
    $('.graph').removeClass("graph").addClass("highlightgraph");
});

$('.graph').click(function(e) {
    $('.highlightabout').removeClass("highlightabout").addClass("about");
    $(this).removeClass("highlightgraph").addClass("graph");
});​
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qYtJ/4/).

Comment: Not entirely the effect I wanted, but maybe that was because I didn't explain my situation properly. Anyway I posted the answer, thank you for your help.